# Exposing delegate through properties in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties

How can I expose delegate through via a property? I am exposing a delegate which is a member of a third party class through my class.

```
public CardInformationAvailable OnDataRecieve //CardInformationAvailable is a delegate type
{
   set
   {
       _cardReaderBase.OnDataReady += value;  // OnDataReady is a delegate of type   
                                              //CardInformationAvailable 
       // Where will  i call -=value?
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually understand what you are trying to do or why, can you expand on your question please.

Comment: I agree with Cicada, use `event`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure on the question, but you can wrap events in this way if you want to expose via your class. But as others have mentioned, you could just add the event directly to _cardReaderBase?

```
public CardReader
{
   public event OnDataReady;
   private CardReaderBase _cardReaderBase;

   public event OnDataReady OnDataReadyEvent
   {
      add 
      {
         _cardReaderBase.OnDataReady += value;
      }
      remove
      {
         _cardReaderBase.OnDataReady -= value;
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put like `if` condition for Null parameter. In other words somethign like this:

```
  public CardInformationAvailable OnDataRecieve 
  {

    set
    {

         if(value == null)
           _cardReaderBase.OnDataReady -= value;
         else
           _cardReaderBase.OnDataReady += value; 

     }
  }
```

Comment: The question is about exposing DELEGATE and not EVENT, don't see actually where is the problem in my answer.

Comment: For these requirements there are the special add and remove parameter. Besides that detaching null from a multicastdelegate will not detach the originally attached handler. To detach the handler you have to use it's function pointer.